# jquery $.post and php $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm trying to pass data to php with jquery. I'm getting the data with javascript.

JQuery :

```
$.post("export.php", JSON.stringify(result)); //result is an array of object
```

When i'm using the debugger on chrome I can see something like this in form data:
[{"id":"foo","x":0,"y":1,"z":8,"t":3}]:

But when I'm trying to retrieve this with php, it doesn't work :

```
echo 'Before decode ';
$array=$_POST['data'];
echo 'After decode ';
echo $array;
```

And it's echoing only this : Before decode After decode

What am I missing? (I know I should decode the data to get back an array in php, but I simplified it to see where the problem come from)

Comment: u didnt pass it as data ,  use $.post("export.php", {data : JSON.stringify(result)});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you won't even have to transform the data into JSON:

```
$.post("export.php", { data: result });
```

Alternatively, you'd have to fish the JSON encoded body out from the input stream, i.e.:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

This typically happens if the content type of the request body is not advertised as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send an encoded JSON string and access it through `$_POST['data']` you need to wrap the result in an object with key `data`:

```
$.post("export.php", {data: JSON.stringify(result)});
```

Then in your server you can decode it like this:

```
echo 'Before decode ';
$array = json_decode($_POST['data']);
echo 'After decode ';
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Noob in PHP, but I think it should be `$.post("export.php", {data: result});`

Comment: Not according to the jQuery documentation...   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @PratikJoshi See my answer for what the real problem is.

Comment: @koala_dev It's the very first line in the documentation:  `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

Comment: @Brad I see that line, I just don't see how it contradicts my answer. If the OP wants to handle the data as a string and access it through `$_POST['data']` then he needs to pass an object instead of the JSON string

Comment: @koala_dev Your original post kept the JSON-encoding, making it redundant.  In any case, he's posting JSON... he can do that, he just needs to access it differently.  Your post implies (at least the way I'm interpreting it) that the only way to get that data is transmit it differently.

Comment: @koala_dev ,Dont  u think this is better approach ? `$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Comment: @koala_dev With your latest edit, your answer is now completely incorrect.  Nowhere is the data JSON-encoded in your initial post, but you are decoding it later...

Answer (score 1):

try to post your json in `data` variable then you will get `$_POST['data']` on `export.php`

```
$.post("export.php", {data : result});
```

or you can use to get your posted data without variable with `file_get_contents()`

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and the decode it `json_decode()`

Comment: yes, found it weird too, but it's working. I didn't noticed first, but  they also do like that in the example section of the documentation

Comment: @Richard There are many ways to achieve what you want.  What you're doing in your question is posting raw data.  If you actually want to handle raw data, see my answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you post raw JSON data, PHP doesn't know how to decode it, and will not populate `$_POST`.  You have to parse it yourself.  Untested, but try this:

```
print_r(
  json_decode(
    file_get_contents('php://input')
  )
);
```

Note that since you are posting JSON, I highly recommend using `$.ajax` instead so you can set `contentType: 'application/json'`.